# MVC4 and MVC5 in one solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

I have an odd question. Can we have a solution comprising of both MVC4 and MVC5 projects?

The scenario is that there is a common project which is on MVC4 and being used by many other applications, but now we want to create a project in MVC5 or convert the existing template to MVC5, but also want to include that MVC4 project in the new solution.

Will that work?  Will the new MVC5 project be able to work with old MVC4 projects in one solution?

I was following the guideline of conversion but it says to run the `upgrade-package` command and this command updates all packages in the MVC4 project as well, which we don't want to do.

Both projects are targeting .NET Framework 4.5 and using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Two different MVC projects in one _solution_ should be fine, but I doubt they could be deployed to the same web _application_.

Comment: However, the MVC project is usually at the _end_ of the dependency chain - how are other projects "using" an MVC project?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Yes the deployed web app is one but internally it uses other common mvc4 for authentication, logins and registration to the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is just a collection of projects; there's no restriction they they use the same frameworks or dependencies, so it should be fine to have them both in one solution.

You probably cannot, however, deploy them to the same web *application*.  They will likely need to be isolated to different applications in IIS or wherever you deploy them.

If you have dependencies *between* the MVC apps you will likely have problems.  I would recommend moving as much logic that is not critical to the MVC app (classes, business logic, repositories, etc) out of the MVC apps into a common library that is independent of the app that uses it.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Deployed web application is one but internally uses the common one as I mentioned above.